# Is having 2 absolutely positioned elements in one container good practice?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside a container div. They are positioned using absolute positioning next to each other. Their widths are always going to be the same and the width of the container div is always going to be the same. Is this good practice? Or should I use float:left and float:right?

the CSS looks like this:

```
#container
{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:100%;
    width:960px;
}

#left
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px; 
    bottom:0px;
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
}

#right
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:25%; 
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Is this good practice? And if I wanted to use relative positioning, elements that are positioned using relative positioning cannot overlap, can they? I mean, they know where each one of them is, right?

Thanks :D

Comment: You already have 2 valid options:  pick one and use it.  As for relatively positioned elements:  yes, they can overlap (did you try it?).

Comment: So instead of using relative position, it'd be best just to use float:left and float:right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use floats so that you don't have to hard-code the container's height if the content fills up

Answer (score 2):

Using float is a good idea. Float will allow the div to make it flexible in case the width changes. Also you won't have to worry about positioning and displaying side by side..

Answer (score 1):

Just float them both to the `left` and they will be right next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what else you want to put in that box. Positioning elements absolutely will disrupt the text flow of your document, which can give some unwanted results. On the other hand if that is what you want you should definitly use it.

Back to your question: I find it best to avoid positioning absolutely whenever I can, but if you are sure you never want to change the dimensions of the two elements or the dimensions of their container, and there is nothing else in the container, it will not do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not necessary, I wouldn't use `position: absolute;`. Floating is more appropriate in this situation.

In the future, when you have to add more elements or have to make the design compatible in other situations, you'll appreciate that you didn't use `position: absolute;`.